# C# Mocking Framework With Parallel Support

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, parallel-processing

What mocking frameworks in C# allow for parallel execution?  (Thread safety)  I was trying RhinoMocks, but it doesn't work well with parallel execution. These tests are not using external resources.

Background: I'm easing other developers into unit testing with MSTest and wanted to use multiple cores. That part appears to run properly.

Comment: Do you want to run tests in parallel on multiple cores, or run multiple threads within one test case?

Comment: I want to run tests in parallel on multiple cores.

Comment: I was using RhinoMocks 3.6.1 with Xunit 2.1.0 and getting errors when running tests in parallel. I updated RhinoMocks to version 4.0.0-alpha3, and I no longer receive errors when running tests in parallel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

Ok, so I originally posted the outline below because I was confident that it might be something within your tests such as shared state -- it couldn't possibly be RhinoMocks, right? *right??* Well, to your point I think there's something odd with the framework. My sincere apologies!

Using Reflector to casually look at the RhinoMock source, we can see that MockRepository has an internal static field to represent the current mock repository.  Looking at the usages of this field, it appears that this repository is used extensively by the dynamic proxy interceptor which strongly suggests nothing is thread-safe.

Here's an example usage that would use that static field.

```
LastCall.IgnoreArguments();
```

So, to answer your question - I would recommend you try out Moq. [Based on the source](http://code.google.com/p/moq/source/browse/trunk/Source/FluentMockContext.cs), it appears that the Fluent API is static, but it's marked with *[ThreadStatic]*, so it should be okay. Of course this comes with the caveat that you're doing the initial set up of the mocks on the current thread and not across threads.

Let me know how that works.

---

**How to setup Parallel Test Execution in Visual Studio 2010:**

This [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vstsqualitytools/archive/2009/12/01/executing-unit-tests-in-parallel-on-a-multi-cpu-core-machine.aspx) outlines the mechanism to enable parallel test execution. In short, you need to manually edit the testsettings file and add the *parallelTestCount* attribute to the Execution node.  Setting the parallelTestCount to 0 means that it will automatically balance the test execution across the available cores on the machine.

```
<TestSettings>
   <!-- etc -->
   <Execution parallelTestCount="0">
         <!-- etc -->
   </Execution>
   <!-- etc -->
</TestSettings>
```

There are a few caveats:

- It only works for standard MSTest "unit tests" (there are a variety of different tests you can create (ordered, coded ui, custom test extensions, etc). Standard unit tests are the TestClass/TestMethod variety.
- It doesn't support Data Adapters. Thus, no support for parallel database driven tests
- It must run locally.  (You can't run tests distributed over multiple machines in parallel.)

Lastly, and this is the most important one -- the onus is on you to ensure that your tests are thread safe. This means if you use any kind of static singletons or shared-state, you're going to run into issues.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't answer my question. I was asking about a mocking framework and not MSTest. That part already worked.

Comment: Thank you for the update.  I tested with Moq and it does work.